# I think I just proved that Pi + e is irrational, but I know that is unsolved, so I'm wondering where the error in my proof is.

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

I had just finished some work on logic, and decided to attempt to prove some random propositions.

I formed a proof by contradiction for e + π being irrational, the givens are: e is irrational, π is irrational, and euler's identity.

Assume for contradiction, that there exists a rational number Q: such that π+e=Q

Rearranging, π = Q-e

e^(iπ) = e^(i(Q-e))

Distributing, e^(iπ) = e^(iQ-ie)

Using Euler's identity, -1 = e^(iQ-ie)

Using Exponent laws, -1 = (e^iQ)/(e^ie)

Rearranging, -e^ie = e^iQ

Is this enough to prove that it's irrational?

I'm sure there's a mistake somewhere here but I cannot spot it.

Comment: What makes you say that -e^ie = e^iQ is a contradiction?

Comment: Your last step is not "trivial".  If $e^{iQ} + e^{ie} = 0$ it does not immediately follow that $Q$ radians around the unit circle would be equal to $-e$ radians.

Comment: How does your final line imply that $Q$ is irrational?

Comment: I thought that was enough, as i assumed e^ie is irrational. Is e^ie not known to be irrational?

Comment: "I thought that was enough, as i assumed e^ie is irrational. Is e^ie not known to be irrational?"  Why do you assume $e^{iQ}$ is rational?  (But, no, I don't think $e^{ie}$ is known to be irrational (assuming you mean rationals to be extended to complex numbers).  I could be wrong.)  But This is circular.  $-e^{ik} = (-1)\cdot e^{ik} = e^{\pi} e^{ik} = e^{(\pi + k}$.  So are back where you started.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything up to $e^{iQ} = e^{ie}$ makes sense, but the conclusion doesn't follow. If two complex numbers $w$ and $z$ sum to $0$, they're opposite vectors in the complex plane.

It seems that you're confusing this with the relationship between two conjugate complex numbers, say $z = x + iy$ and $\bar{z} = x - iy$ which make angles of equal magnitude but opposite direction. The only problem is: complex conjugates don't tend to sum to zero.

What you have derived:
$$
e^{iQ} = e^{i(\pi + e)} = e^{i\pi} e^{ie} = (-1)\,e^{ie} = -e^{ie}
$$
since an argument of $\pi$ is one half-turn.

What you probably want but the formulas don't give:
$$
e^{iQ} = e^{-ie} 
$$
for which one possible solution is $Q = -e$, which would indeed be a contradiction. But even this doesn't follow, as the exponential function is $2\pi i$ periodic, so the only conclusion you could draw is that $iQ = i(2n\pi) - ie$, or $Q = 2n\pi - e$ which is even less information than you began with.

Comment: Yes, thank you for pinpointing where my brain skipped a step. i mixed up negative angles with opposite points on a circle.

Answer (score 19):

$-e^{ix} = e^{iy}$ implies that $x = y + (2n+1)\pi$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}.$

So in your case, it simply shows that $e = Q + (2n+1)\pi$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z},$ which we knew already from your original assumption since $e = Q - \pi.$

Answer (score 8):

Your final question is, since $$-e^{ie} = e^{iQ},$$ is that enough to prove that $Q$ is irrational?

And the answer is, it is not. In fact $$-e^{ix} = e^{i(x+\pi)}$$ for all $x$.  But knowing whether $x$ is rational or irrational tells you nothing about whether $x+\pi$ is rational or irrational.

So your formula provides no new information.

Comment: I realised that 5 mins after I posted it, because I took the natural log of both sides and ended up with iπ+ie = iQ -> π + e = Q. So no new info. Should I delete the question now, or just mark as answered?

Comment: @IfFishThenSticker:  Once you have accepted an Answer, you can no longer delete your Question.

Comment: You can't take the log of both sides of an equation,  by the way. Euler's formula tells us that $e^{2i\pi}=e^0=1$, but clearly we can't conclude from this that $2i\pi =0$.  The correct conclusion is as @xaphi said: $e^a=e^b$ only tells you that $a=b+2i\pi n$ for some integer $n$.

Comment: thank you for the help.

Comment: Sure, I'm sorry it didn't work out for you, but of course you knew it couldn't be that easy. Keep working on it though.